# Is there a way to play Star Trek Voyager: Elite Force on a modern Mac?

Tags: applications

I have a mid-2010 (Intel) MacBook Pro, and I’m nostalgic for [*Star Trek Voyager: Elite Force*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_Voyager_%E2%80%93_Elite_Force), which was released in the early 2000s (!). At some point there was a freely-downloadable Carbon version to allow people who already owned the game to play it under then-current versions of Mac OS X, but as far as I know there hasn’t been any development recently. Can anyone think of some way I might be able to get the game running again?

Comment: Did your computer ship with Lion or Snow Leopard? What version of the OS is it currently running?

Comment: It shipped with 10.6.3 and is running 10.7.2 now. (I said this was a mid-2011 model, but it was mid-2010—fixed now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running Snow Leopard in a virtual machine will run PPC and some carbon apps on a Lion Mac.

You can also install Snow Leopard onto another drive (external or partition) and boot to 10.6 I that's all you need for that app.

Answer (score 1):

The Multiplayer is playable on Intel Macs with this binary: http://thilo.kickchat.com/efport-progress/bin/macosx/

Unfortunately I can't find something for the Single Player.

**Edit:** It is also just 32 bit and won't run on macOS 10.15 Catalina or later.

Comment: Looks like with macOS 10.14 Mojave the Multiplayer (Holomatch) does not launch anymore. Not sure why. `spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=111 label=org.icculus.quake3.85656 path=/Applications/Elite Force/Elite Force Holomatch.app/Contents/MacOS/iostvoyHM-1.37.ub flags=1`

Comment: It works if I start it from the Terminal with sudo: `sudo /Applications/Elite\ Force/Elite\ Force\ Holomatch.app/Contents/MacOS/iostvoyHM-1.37.ub`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the single player version of the game work on a Core Duo MacBook running Mac OS 10.4.11. The problem is if you try to save the game the entire computer would crash. The game crashes immediately when using the same computer on Mac OS 10.5. On a Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.6 the game will load but crashes the entire system if you try to save a game.

I have two theories on how to play this game on a modern Mac.

1. Download the playstation 2 version of the game and play it in an emulator.
2. Buy the good old games version and try to play it using WINE.